# Angular list find visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say you have a variable called `users` that is an `array`

now you have the following `ng-repeat`

```
ng-repeat="user in users | filterUser: searchUser: assignedUsers: selectedDivision"
```

Now after filtering your users using `searchUser` amd `selectedDivision` you wish to collect all the `users` that are visible.

Does `Angular` provide a way to do this and avoid a redudant loop ?

**NOTE**

Ive accepted the answer below however i did find another easy way of doing it:

```
ng-repeat="user in filteredUsers = (users | filterUser: searchUser: assignedUsers: selectedDivision)"
```

This will create create a variable in your `$scope` called `filteredUsers` that contains only the visible users!

Comment: Can't you use the filter in the controller (and store the result in `$scope` or `this`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions :

- Create your own filter method on controller and store it in the $scope for displaying and retrieving
- Call the angular filter in your controller with same attributes
  $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

Show more : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter